# SVG only attr( y ) does not work immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

Big project, everything works fine. At a mouse click bars (see image) should get a different order, by changing the .attr( y ).

[image]

```js
$( canvas ).find( 'rect.bear.'+cur )
        .css( 'fill', bearkleur )
        .attr( 'y', 0 )
        .attr( "x", midden - bearbreedte )
        .attr( "width", bearbreedte )
        .attr( "height", hoogte-2 )
        .css( "opacity", opa );
```

Now, the strangest thing is, that only the **.attr( y )** does not work immediately. After another action that triggers a few seconds later, things arrange as they should **via the same code**.

So, first .attr( y ) doesn't work, then it does. All other attributes and css are updated correctly on the svg objects.

Any idea on how and why this is possible and on how to fix this without strange workarounds?

Thanks.

EDIT: when i use animate() for the .attr( y ), the y-position does change. Bizar.

Comment: Can you include the svg code?

Answer (score 0):

Without the rest of your code, it's hard to tell what the problem is. If you run the snippet below, and click the rectangle, you'll see it works fine. I did combine your calls to `.attr` and removed the `.css` call.

```js
var bearkleur = "blue";
var midden = 100;
var bearbreedte = 75;
var hoogte = 8;
var opa = 0.5;
var canvas = $('svg');



$(".bear").click(function() {
  $(canvas).find('rect.bear')
    .attr({
      y: 0,
      x: midden - bearbreedte,
      width: bearbreedte,
      height: hoogte - 2,
      opacity: opa,
      fill: bearkleur,
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="200" height="100" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
  <rect class="bear" x="0" y="50" width="50" height="10" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ted. Indeed the problem cannot be the Y-attr itself. All works fine, this must be something weird.

I found out that the Y-attribute is also the only attribute that is part of an earlier animation, elsewhere in the code. Ripped out the animation and above issue was solved.

The error was in the applied animate function. Never terminated properly, and because of that Y-attr was 'in the middle of something'.

Problem solved.